# I need some clarification regarding this example on Stroustrup's new book about ADL

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

I reproduce below the argument-dependent lookup (ADL) example given in pages 396 and 397 of Stroustrup book (4th edition):

```
namespace N {
    struct S { int i; };
    void f(S);
    void g(S);
    void h(int);
};

struct Base {
    void f(N::S);
};

struct D : Base {
    void mf(N::S);

    void g(N::S x)
    {
        f(x);   // call Base::f()
        mf(x);  // call D::mf()
        h(1);   // error: no h(int) available
    }
};
```

What the comments say above is correct (I've tested it), but that doesn't seem to agree with what the author says in the next paragraph:

> In the standard, the rules for argument-dependent lookup are phrased
>   in terms of *associated namespaces* (iso §3.4.2). Basically:
>
> - If an argument is a class member , the associated namespaces are the class itself (including its base classes) and the class's
>     enclosing namespaces.
> - If an argument is a member of a namespace, the associated namespaces are the enclosing namespaces.
> - If an argument is a built-in type, there are no associated namespaces.

In the example, `x`, which has type `N::S` is not a member of class `D`, nor of its base `Base`. But it's a member of `namespace N`. According to the second bullet above, the function `N::f(S)` should be the one called, instead of `Base::f()`.

The result above also doesn't seem to agree with the second bullet in paragraph 3.4.2p2 in the Standard, which says:

> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are:
>   the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its
>   direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the
>   namespaces of which its associated classes are members. Furthermore,
>   if T is a class template specialization, its associated namespaces and
>   classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters
>   (excluding template template parameters); the namespaces of which any
>   template template arguments are members; and the classes of which any
>   member templates used as template template arguments are members.

Comment: ADL kicks in only if the function is not found with regular lookup.

Comment: @n.m incorrect. The rule is that ADL is disabled if the normal lookup finds a local actual function declaration (i.e a `{ void f(); ..`) or a class member function. All other normally found declarations (including local using declarations) still allow ADL to be done.

Comment: @n.m. If that were true, then the moment you implemented `operator<<` for your class in a global namespace, you would no longer be able to write `std::cout << std::string("Hello");`. This of course does not happen.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb um, that's what I mean. Are there any other "normally found" declarations?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ah, OK, I see, there are other normally found declarations. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **3.4.2/3** Let `X` be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let `Y` be the lookup set produced by argument dependent
>   lookup (defined as follows). If `X` contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then Y is empty. Otherwise...

So basically, ADL doesn't kick in when the ordinary lookup finds a member function or local (block-scope) function declaration (or something that's not a function). It does kick in when the ordinary lookup finds a stand-alone namespace-scope function, or when it finds nothing at all.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. But I still don't understand the example in 3.4.2p3: `g(parm, 1)`, 1 is an int, not a float !

Comment: There's a local (block-scope) declaration of `extern void g(NS::T, float);` in `main`. This suppresses ADL, per second bullet point above.